# Не получается написать «универсальный» makefile

Tags: makefile, c++

Возникла необходимость написать на С++ небольшую программу (500-1К строк), а с IDE я как-то не дружу (программируя на python и java обхожусь sublime'ом), да и хотелось узнать, как компилировать программы из консоли. Поэтому я написал "классовый" HelloWorld и начал читать [этот мануал](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=100976.0). Проблемы возникли при написании универсального makefile'a.

"Захардкоженный" makefile выглядит так (всё лежит в одной папке):

```
all: Greetings

Greetings: main_greetings.o greetings_printer.o
    g++ -o Greetings main_greetings.o greetings_printer.o

greetings_printer.o: GreetingsPrinter.cpp
    g++ -c -o greetings_printer.o GreetingsPrinter.cpp

main_greetings.o: Greetings.cpp
    g++ -c -o main_greetings.o Greetings.cpp
```

и команда

```
make -f makefile.makefile
```

делает всё, что нужно: программа компилируется и работает.

Но вот попытка написать универсальный makefile оборачивается провалом.
Сам makefile:

```
TARGET  = $( shell basename 'pwd' )
SOURCES = $( wildcard *.cpp ) 
OBJECTS = $( SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o )

all: $(TAGRET)

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)

$(TAGRET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $(TAGRET) $(LDFLAGS) $(OGJECTS) $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(TAGRET)

.PHONY: all clean
```

а предыдущий вызов из консоли выдаёт такой результат:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

В чём ошибка?

---

Попробовал вот так:

```
make Greetings
```

Вывод:

```
g++     Greetings.cpp   -o Greetings
/tmp/ccGdTOxR.o: In function `main':
Greetings.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `MyGreetingsPrinter::MyGreetingsPrinter()'
Greetings.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `MyGreetingsPrinter::PrintGreetings()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Greetings] Error 1
```

Хотя с первой версией makefile программа работала без ошибок.

Comment: а в строке

    TARGET  = $( shell basename 'pwd' )

кавычки точно правильные? как по мне, так там нужны обратные кавычки.

Comment: @KoVadim

Поменял. Результат тот же.

Comment: с прямыми кавычками у Вас TARGET всегда будет pwd.

попробуйте запустить так

    make -d all

и попытаться разобраться, что пошло не так

Comment: @KoVadim
После этой команды идёт очень-очень большой вывод, если будет необходимо -- скину весь. Вся соль, наверное, в этой строке:

`Considering target file `makefile'.`

Comment: там начало вывода более-менее стандартно. Самое интересное начинается в последних строках после строки "Updating goal targets....".

Судя по всему, оно почему то решило, что цель называется makefile. А так как это файл у вас есть, то и выполнять нечего.

Comment: Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `all'.
 File `all' does not exist.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `all'.
Must remake target `all'.
Successfully remade target file `all'.
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

Comment: первое - а make clean отрабатывает? второе - а после clean работает all правильно?
не изменяйте вопрос. Коментарии не бесконечны. Поменялся вопрос - этот закрыли, открыли новый.

А то даже не понятно, о чем все коментарии.

Comment: @Montreal: Вы рассчитываете на то, что `shell basename 'pwd'` выдаст вам `Greetings`? (А как называется ваш makefile? `Greetings.makefile`?)

Comment: @VladD, дело в том, что я совсем не понимаю, как работает эта система и делаю всё по инструкции, ссылку на которую дал в самом начале. Сейчас читаю мануал по make, но он смущает объёмами и фразой "как читать этот мануал". Мой makefile назывался просто makefile, но я попробовал его переименовать и получил на `make`: `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.` Сейчас хочу последовать совету @KoVadim и открыть другой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

судя по всему, в этой строке опечатка (не те кавычки):

```
TARGET  = $( shell basename 'pwd' )
```

вероятно, должно быть так:

```
TARGET  = $( shell basename `pwd` )
```

тогда в переменную `TARGET` будет записано имя текущего каталога, а не строка `pwd`.

> make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
>   В чём ошибка?

никакой ошибки нет. просто программе `make` нечего делать. что бы ни было записано в `TARGET` (`pwd` или имя текущего каталога), вероятно, файл или каталог с таким именем уже имеется в текущем каталоге, и время его последнего обновления больше (т.е., он «моложе»), чем у любого из файлов с суффиксом `.o`.

Answer (score 1):

При вызове функций make недопустимы пробелы между `$(` и именем функции. Пробел перед закрывающей скобкой также не нужен, ибо он будет записан в переменную.
Уберите лишние пробелы и конечно используйте обратные кавычки:

```
TARGET  = $(shell basename `pwd`)
```

Но всё уже есть в самом make, поэтому проще будет так:

```
TARGET  = $(notdir $(PWD))
```

Зависимости *.o от *.cpp make отслеживает автоматически.
Как вызывать компилятор он тоже знает, ему только нужно сообщить какие подключать библиотеки:

```
LDLIBS=-lm
```

где их искать:

```
LDFLAGS=-L../mylibs
```

и флаги для g++:

```
CXXFLAGS=-O3
```

т.е. ваша строка с `$(CXX)` и т.д. не нужна.

[Подробнее о переменных make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html)

Answer (score 0):

В этой строке

```
    $(CXX) -o $(TAGRET) $(LDFLAGS) $(OGJECTS) $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)
```

похоже, опечатка: `OGJECTS` вместо `OBJECTS`